# Is the 'My Contacts' System Contact Group always a subset of the contacts in people.connections.list? - Google People API

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

I am working with the Google People API.

I would like to know if the set of contacts that can be retrieved from `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/contactGroups/myContacts` is strictly a subset of the set of contacts that can be retrieved from `https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections`.

Please let me know if this can or cannot be guaranteed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this should be the case.

The former does return all of your contacts under a certain group. Using `myContacts` will return all your contacts.

The latter returns all of your contacts as well.

You can ask other people to execute the links below to confirm it and respond back to you.

[https://people.googleapis.com/v1/contactGroups/myContacts](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/get?authuser=1&apix_params=%7B%22resourceName%22%3A%22contactGroups%2FmyContacts%22%2C%22maxMembers%22%3A1000%2C%22fields%22%3A%22memberResourceNames%22%7D)
[https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me/connections](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people.connections/list?apix_params=%7B%22resourceName%22%3A%22people%2Fme%22%2C%22personFields%22%3A%22names%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22connections%2FresourceName%22%7D)

Comment: Do you have any sources, any part of the documentation that states that they both return all contacts?

Comment: At the links I provided, only the connections has a proper description and it was `Provides a list of the authenticated user's contacts.`. contactGroups on the other hand doesn't define the specific group `myContacts` and any other else but all we have is its formatted name "My Contacts" which is a system contact group and is assumed that returns all "My Contacts" of the user which is proven by multiple tests across multiple accounts of mine and other colleagues. So unless we do have a proper documentation of the system contact groups available provided by google saying otherwise, this is true

Comment: There is another contact group `all` which has a formatted name "All Contacts". I can't see a difference on what they return aside from you can only add members on `myContacts` between the two via `https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups.members/modify` (together with `starred`). Any other else only have the option of members being removed.

Comment: @BenBoyle, may I know what do you want to achieve? Maybe there's something we can do about it.

Comment: I think that's sufficient information. Thank you for testing.